# Revert git repo to penultimate commit while ditching last commit

Tags: git

I found several answers on how to revert to a previous commit but each one is slightly different from my situation. I want to go back in time to the instant where I just committed the penultimate commit, as if my last commit never existed. I want this result permanently not temporarily.

In the screenshot below, the first commit if the one I want to destroy entirely.
 The second one ("Adjusted text styling...") is the one I want to become my last commit. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a `git reset --hard HEAD~1` and then push --force your remote branches (if you had already pushed the revision you want to get rid of).

Comment: another way: ```git reset --hard 62e175739```

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by push --force my remote branches though? Note: this is all about the master branch (other branches must stay untouched)

Comment: Once you do that on a local branch, if you got other remote repos set up where that branch had already been pushed, those remote branches won't move. If´ that's the case, you would have to push your "new" branch position... and if you try to push _without_ forcing, git will reject you because the remote branches would have a revision that is not part of the history of the branch you are trying to push.... so --force will be needed. If you have no remote repos set up (or if you have remote repos but the branch hadn't been pushed yet) then you don't have to do anything else.